# How to add a Bootstrap4 template in Angular6 project?

Tags: angular, angular6

I tried to split bootstrap components to Angular way. But after ng build in port 4200 it's not showing anything but a white screen. There are lot of js, json,images, css ,scss. How do I add it all to the angular project?

Comment: its difficult to understand what you are actually trying to do, if possible please provide a sample code.

Comment: I have a bootstrap4  landing page template ...I have to implement it in an angular 6 project .. and initially frontend to be complete to fulfill with more functionality in project..

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are many existing tutorials sites to help you get started with Angular. Have a look at [angular.io](https://angular.io/start) **,** [blog.angular-university.io](https://angular-university.io/) **or** [alligator.io](https://alligator.io/).